# Adding Parallel Diodes to a load

Tags: diodes, parallel, switching, load

This question is based on my previous question - [Measuring voltage drop across a diode in a switched circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475113/measuring-voltage-drop-across-a-diode-in-a-switched-circuit)

I have started a bounty on that question. At the same time, I am trying to understand why is that happening as I still didn't get a proper answer.

So, I tried to understand by trying different simulations.

I tried simulating just a voltage source, with adding parallel diodes and a load.

[image]

My questions :

When I have only one diode connected to the load, the voltage at the load is around 4.474V
When I have 2 diodes in parallel and voltage at the load is around 4.50V
When I place 3 diodes in parallel as shown in the image above, the voltage at the load is around 4.53V

1. What is happening here, when I add diodes in parallel?

Yes, I agree and have been told that adding diodes in parallel is not a good thing to do. But I am just trying to understand the basics of what might happen when diodes are in parallel?

If could also help me with my previous question, it would be beneficial for me.

Answer (score 3):

The diodes drop less voltage when the current through them is less. If you  parallel three perfectly matched diodes and maintain them at exactly the same junction temperature, the current will split evenly between them so it will be 1/3 through each and the voltage drop will be a bit less.

For example, compare the [1N400x](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1N4001-D.PDF) diodes:

[image]

If you reduce the current from 300mA to 100mA each, the voltage drop will decrease from about 860mV to 790mV at Tj = 25°C.

Of course, in reality the diodes are not going to be perfectly matched and the junctions will not be at the same temperature (especially if one of them starts hogging more current it will get hotter than the others).

Comment: Ok thank you. But how does current splits in the diodes? Diodes are not resistors in parallel, right ?

Comment: By symmetry the current will split equally. As you can see they behave a bit like resistors in that the voltage drop goes up with current (and over a narrow range you can linearize the response). In the case I mentioned above they (over that 100mA to 300mA range) have  dynamic resistance of about 70mV/200mA = 0.35\$\Omega\$. So over that range you could consider them as  an ideal-ish diode with 755mV drop and 0.35 ohms in series.

Comment: Look at the Vf vs If curves Sephro provided.  At any given point along one of the curves, the diode acts like a resistor with a resistance of Vf/If.

Comment: Ok. So, diodes do behave as resistors, right?

Comment: And if you also could help me with the previous bounty question, it would be beneficial for me

Comment: @Newbie I would not say that, but their voltage drop increases with increasing current.